# Wordpress registration without wp-login.php and wp-admin folder, is it possible?

Tags: users, user-registration

If i know well, the Wordpress use the wp-login.php to login/logout and register new users. Is it possible to make custome registration without wp-login.php and wp-admin folder?

Comment: Yes, You can create a custom script that would insert users in database, don't really see how it would be better than using the wp registration form though ...